# Make new list from source list at index 0, find matching items in second list and append to that new list at index 1

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have a scrip that I'd like to take source data `list1` and pull data from it. `models` is a list that contains index[0] of each item in `list1` and now I'd like to append or insert a specific item from `list1` if it's found in `list2`, to the first index to produce something like the below. Note the items I want to match from `list2` wont always be in the same index found in `list1`.

> models = [['model1', 'TT42'], ['model2', 'GG50'], ['model3', 'BB12']]

```
list1 = [['model1', 'yes', 'TT42'], 
        ['model2', 'yes', 'GG50'],
        ['model3', 'no', 'BB12']]

models = []
for item in list1:
    if item[0] not in models:
        models.append(item[0])
#  models = ['model1', 'model2', 'model3']

list2 = ['TT42', 'GG50', 'BB12']

for item in list1:
    for element in item:
        if element in list2:
            models.insert(1, element)
print(models)
#  models = [model1, TT42, TT42, TT42, model2. model3]
#  what am I missing?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a list of strings. It looks like your intent with the insert function is to insert into a list, but the object is a string, and that won't create a 2D list like you intend. I think this fixes your code. Note that I appended a list, making a 2D list as desired:

```
list1 = [['model1', 'yes', 'TT42'], 
        ['model2', 'yes', 'GG50'],
        ['model3', 'no', 'BB12']]

list2 = ['TT42', 'GG50', 'BB12']

model = []

for item2 in list2:
    for row in list1:
        if item2 in row:
            model.append([row[0],item2])

print(model)
```

Comment: Hi @Drew Bermudez. This is closer to my output, however now it's printing `['model2', 'GG50'], repeatedly. Could it be that my source `list1` contains multiple of the same data? As in multiple of `['model2', 'GG50']. It seems to ignore the first couple rows in `list1` though.

Comment: @Chaotic.Python can you please share what list1 and list2 input do this so I can replicate your issue?

Comment: No that was me getting confused and thinking it worked out, I changed the variable names so it made sense in my head and with my project. You're help was the correct solution so noted as deserved! Thank you sir.

Comment: Haha no worries! Glad I could help <3

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [['model1', 'yes', 'TT42'], 
        ['model2', 'yes', 'GG50'],
        ['model3', 'no', 'BB12']]

list2 = ['TT42', 'GG50', 'BB12']

models = []

for find in list2:
    for item in list1:
        if find == item[2]:
            models.append([item[0],find])
            break

print(models)
```

Comment: Sundrajat, This is returning `[]` I think because the items we noted as `find` wont always be at index[2] of list1. It needs to look at any index.